# MySQL Query Join Table

Tags: mysql, join

Both search bring back the correct results, but when I tried combining the 2 queries, it ends up giving bad results.

```
$query3 = "SELECT *
FROM airport_countries, airports
WHERE airports.iso_country=airport_countries.code &&
airport_countries.name like '%$search%'
ORDER BY pageviews DESC";

$query2 = "SELECT * 
    FROM airports 
    WHERE name like '%$search%' or 
municipality like '%$search%'
ORDER BY pageviews DESC";
```

VVVVVVVVV

```
SELECT *
FROM airport_countries, airports
WHERE airports.iso_country=airport_countries.code &&
airport_countries.name like '%$search%' or
    airports.name like '%$search%'  or 
airports. municipality like '%$search%'
ORDER BY pageviews DESC
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't actually know the MySQL '&&' operator can be used in this case... but 'AND' instead.
'&&' should be used for binary operations.

Comment: It would also be great if you explained what "bad results" means.

Comment: Bad results meaning, it is giving me way too many results. Some of the results do not appear in either query (when queried separately).

Comment: The query is changing airports.name from what it is suppose to be to the 2nd and 3rd airport.name results. So for example the 2nd airport name is London and the 3rd is Luton; it pulls in 20000 results and changes all the names to London/Luton. The correct results should be closer to say 100, each with a distinct name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you problem aseems to be the [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html). to avoid that, just use braces:

```
SELECT *
FROM airport_countries, airports
WHERE airports.iso_country=airport_countries.code
AND (
    airport_countries.name LIKE '%$search%'
    OR airports.name LIKE '%$search%'
    OR airports. municipality LIKE '%$search%'
    )
ORDER BY pageviews DESC
```

i'd also recommend using `AND` instead of `&&` (you're writing `or` instead of `||` - doesn't look very consistent), but thats just my opinion for better readability and shouldn't cause any difference.